# Как разработчику-одиночке эффективнее начать писать сложный проект?

Tags: .net, проект, ux, it-бизнес

*На этот вопрос наверное сложно ответить объективно, но он очень актуален для меня, постараюсь как можно лучше конкретизировать, дочитайте до конца.*

Я занимаюсь и веб-разработкой (фронтенд) и десктоп-разработкой (.NET). Опыт работы с очень большими проектами у меня есть, в основном как у овнера продукта/заказчика.

Большой проект начинается с написания основополагающей документации по примерно таким этапам:

1. Бизнес-видение - зачем и что мы хотим в итоге получить?
2. Высокоуровневые требования - пучок больших фичей
3. Минимальный жизнеспособный продукт - выбор из списка фичей того, без чего продукт нельзя запустить в релиз
4. Проект архитектуры приложения и выбор технологического стека
5. Общий дизайн-концепт интерфейса и брендирование
6. Спецификации выбранных фичей - декомпозиция, фунциональная логика фичей, детальное описание каждой фичи с учетом удобства для пользователя
7. Постановка задач разработчикам, начало разработки, прототипирование

Итого, чтобы начать вообще что-либо писать, требуется огромная куча работы, в идеале команды из человек десяти, минимум недели на 2.

Обычно у одиночек это происходит так - "давай слепим какой-нибудь интерфейс, пропишем в коде поведение для каждого его элемента, и готово". Процесс понимания того, что ты должен сделать и того что пишешь в коде происходит одновременно, или даже код бежит вперёд понимания, в результате получается "разработка методом тыка", а потом либо большие удивлённые глаза заказчика "будь осторожен в своих желаниях", либо понимание, что "надо всё переписывать".

То есть вижу 2 крайности: полный цикл разработки и тяп-ляп-в-продакшн. Где золотая середина для разработчика-одиночки, которому надо провести проект от заказа до публикации? Проблема всегда одна: лучший КПД разработчика в кратчайшие сроки.

**Вопрос следующий:** вот к примеру, я один, есть например конкретная словесная задача "написать еще один Телеграм-клиент" и есть понимание о стеке, например ".NET WPF + MVVM", хотя это не важно в контексте данного вопроса. А дальше то что? Как это делают профессионалы?

Comment: Начать писать сложный проект мало, надо еще и закончить. xD

Comment: Тут главное, это понять, чем и для кого новый проект будет лучше уже существующих. А прежде всего -- буду ли я сам в основном только им пользоваться. Если ответ утвердительный, то реализовываете  в первую очередь то, что именно вам нужно. Когда сами понабивали шишки и теперь довольны результатом, то можно показывать другим и слушать их хотелки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Дисклеймер: тут нет "правильного" ответа. У каждого он будет свой.

Однако, "хренак-хренак и в продакшн" более перспективный метод, т.к. "практика — главный критерий истины". Пока теоретик будет проектировать свои ажурные замки в облаках, практик набьет шишек и уже встретится с реальностью и она будет его направлять.

Старайтесь придерживаться CI\CD - в любой момент времени проект у вас должен собираться и разворачиваться для предъявления потенциальному пользователю. Даже если вы перепахиваете большую системную часть - делайте это за Фасадом и/или с сохранением рабочей "ветки". Если проект застрянет в неработоспособном состоянии, велик риск, что вы его там и забросите навеки.

Второй аспект - написание кода не так сильно отличается по сути от написания документации. И то и то - проектирование. И там и там возможны переделки по ходу. Если вы будете писать код от общего к частному, то вполне сможете минимизировать "большие удивлённые глаза" и понимание, что "надо всё переписывать".

Третий аспект - вы же не будете писать проект в одиночку от начала и до конца? У вас появятся пользователи, спонсоры, инвесторы и коллеги, сообщество, и т.п. Чем раньше вы сможете завлечь их и поддерживать интерес, тем больше они смогут вам помочь в дальнейшем. Детальное ТЗ может привлечь инвестора, а приятный MVP (Minimum Viable Product) - пользователя.

---

Касательно работы одному, тут тоже индивидуально, но главная проблема, обычно - мотивация. Написание документации для самого себя вещь неплохая (помогает разложить все по полочкам, перепроверить себя, по сути как rubber duck debugging), но быстро надоедает, а следование ей превращается в изнурительный труд на галерах. Продуктивнее может быть последовательное установление и достижение MVP целей, когда у вас максимально рано появляется что-то чем можно пользоваться, хвастаться и предъявлять как "достижение". А каждая достигнутая мини-цель - буст к мотивации продолжать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он у меня в принципе не вызывает противоречий, но не прояснилось примерно ничего.

Comment: @aepot поэтому вопрос и будет скорее всего закрыт, как "Невозможно дать объективный ответ" ))) А что бы вы хотели, прямое указание что и как вам делать? Вы все равно не согласитесь. То что кто-то угадает как вам хочется в душе - ну тоже не гарантия успеха. Может быть вы просто откладываете выбор и переход к действиям?

Comment: В данный момент я не стою перед выбором, что делать, я в свбодные выходные пытаюсь выработать базовую методику в подходе к таким проектам. Объективность а такого рода вопросах - штука весьма размазанная. Хожу по грани закрытия вопроса, тоже верно, но я не нашел пока другого способа найти помощи. Все мои знакомые профессиональные разрабы - исключительно командные игроки и мало чем мне могут помочь. Возможно, если из вашего ответа сформулировать короткую методичку и немного доработать, он окажнтся принятым. Мысль то верная.

Comment: @aepot я в одиночку пилю большой проект уже больше 8 лет, какой-то опыт есть. **Главное - мотивация**. Если она стабильно есть, то даже переписывание больших частей - не страшно. А если её нет - как ни тасуй, все равно забросишь. Поэтому я для себя вижу вопрос больше в ключе "как поддержать мотивацию в большом проекте" - отсюда и фокус на MVP и налегание на CI/CD.

Answer (score 3):

Надо начать делать, в вашем случае - писать.

Обычно, я боюсь начинать сложные и большие проекты из-за их... сложности. Поэтому я сначала смотрю примерные проекты у остальных, смотрю как они реализованы, и после этого начинаю писать архитектуру, основываясь на том, что я увидел. После этого, смотря на размер того, что я написал, я разбиваю это на маленькие задачи. Поверьте, это действительно помогает и так проще делать большой проект, разбив его на пункты или задачи. Потом, при возникновении какой-то проблемы, я начинаю разбирать этот пункт тщательнее.

Разумеется, разобраться с технологиями (как вы написали в вопросе) это нужно, причем на старте, но не нужно хвататься за первую технологию, которую вы знаете. Возможно, она не очень подходит для этой задачи и могут получиться сплошные костыли да палки.

Поэтому, обобщая весь мой ответ, я советую посравнивать, почитать, посмотреть как это имплементировано у других, разбить на маленькие задачи, и начать выполнять большой проект по задачам. Вот увидите, это будет несложно :)

Это был пример из моего опыта, надеюсь, он вам пригодиться ;)

Comment: `Обычно, я боюсь начинать сложные и большие проекты из-за их... сложности.` Как же я вас понимаю, я обычно из-за размера боюсь. Как выпишу задачи, так и выпаду в осадок на несколько месяцев. Но если всё-таки начать и сделать хоть что-то, дальше обычно с кайфом идёт :)

Comment: Когда папка с проектом создана, в ней есть основные файлы и они даже как-то запускаются, аж дышать легче становится