# Возможна ли интеграция инстаграм бота и гугл таблицы в android приложении и в вебсайте

Tags: python, java, c#, c++, бот

Я **новенький** в этой сфер, однако прошел самый простецкий путь, типо, калькулятор, часов и прочего такого. Я хочу создать приложение и вебсайт для тату мастеров в моей стране (Латвия), суть приложения заключается в почти полной и простой **автоматизации** записей на сеанс и создания эскизов. И так, у меня есть несколько вопросов по этому поводу:

1. Возможно ли интегрировать инстаграмм-бота и нужно ли его создавать с нуля или хватит тупо купить?  Выглядеть это должно примерно так:
   Я Швабра, которая хочет записаться к мастеру Ведро, я заполняю анкету в приложении, указываю в нем свой айди инстаграмма, выбранный эскиз и из календаря рядом с формой число(заведомо выбранные Ведром), затем бот отправляет вчю эту информацию тату мастеру Ведру, указывает название(а лучше картинку) эскиза, после чего они обговаривают все нюансы с Шваброй уже в инстаграме.
2. Второй вопрос такой, после выбора даты, можно ли это на автомате перенести в любую существующюю таблицу (желательно гугл таблицы ибо опыт с ней огромный), к примеру: Швабра хочет придти к мастеру Ведро 12 мая, после подтверждения от Ведра в приложении или на сайте в отдельной таблице появляется вся информация о сеансе в одной строке.
3. Какой язык программирования лучше выбрать для приложения на андроид? С сайтом хватит обычного css html и javascript думаю.

---

Если нужны какие-то подробности, которые помогут вам помочь мне, задавайте. Это только небольшая часть идеи для введения в курс дела.

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень общий, он бесполезен другим участникам, и противоречит правилам ресурса, на котором вы находитесь. Ну а по вопросам: 1. Чат есть? Доступ к нему программно получить можно? Если да, то возможно. "С нуля или купить?" - а разница? Что там человек будет с нуля делать, что там, отличие лишь в ваших силах, если не способны на такое, то покупайте время фрилансера. 2. Таблицы не используют в программировании, в программировании используют базы, или простую сериализацию данных (JSON и пр), а уже от туда можно вывести куда угодно. 3. Любой, поддерживаемый данной OS.

Comment: Таблица служит для того, чтобы тату-мастер не ввёл её сам, однако это изначально спорная часть, я думвю просто заменить это информацией в профиле со стороны мастера и клиента. Насчет полезности, я, честно говоря не знаю, может у кого-то возникнет аналогичный вопрос с ботом, так как это не такое частое слияние именно с инстаботом. Однако, спасибо за ответ. К слову, чат будет, чтобы клиент и мастер сами решали где им проще общаться, я лишь хочу облегчить процесс, ибо на опыте знаю как это тяжко.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше сообщение похоже на вопрос-прокрастинацию, [я сам когда-то этим грешил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1407452/373567). Если не уверены в своих силах - либо пытайтесь, пробуйте хоть что-то реализовать не смотря на сомнения. Либо лучше не беритесь.

Нужна экспертиза от профессионала - пишите Техническое Задание на разработку. Не важно, кто будет именно писать код, вы или кто-то другой. Имея качественное ТЗ на руках, вы сможете получить консультацию и прояснить какие-то непонятности. Что-то даже прояснится, пока вы это самое ТЗ пишете.

А так на вопрос "как сделать красиво?" есть простой ответ: "садись и делай". Чтобы что-то уметь, надо чему-то учиться.

А выбор стека технологий - дело субъективное. Есть навыки веб-разработки, значит это веб-стек, а если есть навыки .NET - MAUI ждёт, и так далее. Вариантов, к счастью, много. Достичь желаемого результата возможно независимо от выбранных технологий.

Comment: Хороший ответ, да, пока, к сожалению, это так, в данный момент ноутбук далековато от меня. Как я упомянул, я только начинаю, поэтому у меня вызывает в голове путаницу язык, все пишут, мол Питон и Джава универсальные, однако доказательств в источниках крайне мало, а как узнал, что их обоих можно скомбинировать, ахнул и словил инсульт, однако, я все тау же хочу это сделать и обязательно сделаю, в данном случае вопрос был лишь в том, возможно ли это или нет. Ну и в целом в выборе языка, что не так сильно важно, как я понял.

Comment: @CharonIkh в мире программирования возможно абсолютно всё. Вопрос только в цене.

Comment: Звучит как дорогостоящая цитата